# How does the use of NSOperation mainqueue makes UITableView's scrolling smooth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I wonder how the process associated with `NSOperation` `mainQueue` doesn’t affect `UITableView`'s scrolling.

The main reason of the sluggish scroll in my code is that each cell loading is slow, because each cell has to fetch images from the server.
That’s why I used to create another thread using GCD to handle the fetching process given by each cell. Meanwhile, the main thread handles exclusively tableview’s scroll, which is what I've understood to ensure fast scrolling.

But, in recent days, I’ve noticed a sample code is using `NSOperation`. 
I imitated the part so that the tableview cell is loaded using `NSOperation` `mainQueue`. 
I expected it would tax the tableview’s scroll performance, because the main thread handles both cell loading and tableview scrolling as I understand.

But, surprisingly, it doesn’t. The performance of both cell loading and tableview’s scrolling is perfect.
I still wonder how this can be.

I guess I’m either mistaken or I miss something.
Would you let me know what it is?

Comment: Provide a link to the example code.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Knee-jerks: GCD != threads; don't use blocking image fetches. A blocking image fetch obstructing a thread is less efficient than a non-blocking one attached to a runloop.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS application's main thread consists of two elements:

• The Run Loop

• The Main Queue

> The main dispatch queue is a globally available serial queue that
>   executes tasks on the application’s main thread. This queue works with
>   the application’s run loop (if one is present) to **interleave the**
>   **execution of queued tasks with the execution of other event sources**
>   **attached to the run loop**. Because it runs on your application’s main
>   thread, the main queue is often used as a key synchronization point
>   for an application.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html)

The code you have in your View Controllers is ran on the run loop *(not sure about this one)*. That's why you're not allowed to execute any long lasting tasks.

You can though, delegate these tasks to the Main Queue (and that's what you're doing). When you do that, the OS **interleaves** the execution between the run loop and the main queue (loading the images). That's why scrolling the view is still pretty smooth.

**Why don't we do all async tasks on the main queue then?** you might ask. Because the main queue has to share thread processor time with the run loop, operations will be executed slower than on a background thread. It's not something that you can observe in that example, though.

Answer (score 0):

All iOS UI animations (including scrolling) are performed on separate UI thread. So as long as `UITableView` has all required data (i.e. you provide empty cell until image is loaded) it won't be blocked by any sort of main thread activity.

> Execution of the animations occurs on a secondary thread so as to
>   avoid blocking the current thread or your application’s main thread.

[https://developer.apple.com/.../AnimatingViews.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html)